# Eloquent construction returning too many results

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following code in my DesignsController:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return Design::find($id)->with('variables')->get();
}
```

When I GET /designs/1 I should get back json of just the design with id=1, but I get back all the current designs.

In the design model:

```
/* Define relationship between designs and variables */
public function variables()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Variable');
}
```

The routes.php:

```
Route::resource('designs', 'DesignsController');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: a bit more information. I get all the results back as long as I hit an id of an actual design, so it seems to be finding the result according to the id, but then returning all results.

If I remove `->with('variables')->get();` then this works, but I need the variables too. Here's the model for Design:

```
class Design extends Eloquent {

    /* Define relationship between designs and variables */
    public function variables()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Variable');
    }

        /* Define relationship between designs and variables */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Variable model:

```
class Variable extends Eloquent {
public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: Include the Variable Model if you can. The problem may be in there.

Comment: There's not much in there, but I've edited the post to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing your "with" statement incorrectly:

Eager load:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return Design::with('variables')->find($id);
}
```

Actually I think you're problem was calling get() after find() since find already returns a model. Find should be called at the end of a query you build because it essentially calls get() inside of it.

Lazy-Eager alternative:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return Design::find($id)->load('variables');
}
```

Comment: @babbaggeii oh made a correction to answer, problem was really calling find() first.